# Setting cookie from a JavaScript file on another domain

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

I have a site on domainA.com. It includes `file.js` from domainB.com:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domainB.com/file.js"></script>
```

In `file.js`, I want to be able to set a cookie for domainA.com. How would I do this? It must be possible since Google Analytics does it for their `__utma`, etc. cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot--apparently, this isn't actually a cross domain cookie and you can set it using `document.cookie='blah'`.

Comment: I believe when you include an external script directly in the page via a `<script>` tag it is loaded in the security context of the page. This is the crux of why jsonp can be used for cross-domain communication.